# How can I reload a vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I know the solution is update the prop data like this :

```
this.selectedContinent = ""
```

But I want to use another solution

After I read some reference, the solution is :

```
this.$forceUpdate()
```

I try it, but it does not work

Demo and full code like this :

https://jsfiddle.net/Lgxrcc5p/13/

You can click button test to try it

I need a solution other than update the property data

Answer (score 56):

You have to assign a key to your component. When you want to re-render a component, you just update the key.
More info [here](http://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/).

```
<template>
    <component-to-re-render :key="componentKey" />
</template>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      componentKey: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    forceRerender() {
      this.componentKey += 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: component methods stop working after this

Comment: how to reload it from inside?

Comment: @rendom to reload from inside you can emit an event to parent component and tell it to do the reload

Answer (score 5):

I use v-if to render the component:

```
<div id="app">
      <button type="button" @click="updateComponent">test</button>
      <test-el v-if="show"></test-el>
</div>
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/lakerswgq/5tkbaba8/2/)

Comment: this worked for me - I set data.show default false then set to true and the component is rendered.

Comment: Instead of v-if, use :key="componentKey" [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/allenyllee/fbw7mnra/1/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Object.assign` to assign initial data properties.

Instead of `this.$forceUpdate()`

You should use `Object.assign(this.$data,this.$options.data.call(this))`.

Here we using this.$options.data get original data and assigning this values to this.$data.

See the updated fiddle [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Lgxrcc5p/15/).

**Update**:

Another method: [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Lgxrcc5p/17/)

Comment: On the your fiddle itu works. But on my real case, it does not work. In my real case, I must refresh the page. Do you have another solution to update whole of component without refresh the page?

Comment: I have added another method.

Comment: It seems it can not be used in my real case. My real case like this : `<template>
    ...
</template>
<script>
    export default{
        props: [...],
        data() {
            return {
              ...
           };
        },
        computed:{
            ....
        }
    };
</script>`.  It can not define a function

Comment: You can add the initialState() function before export default it your script tag.

Comment: I had add it. But, there are some errors. It looks like your second solution does not fit my real case

Comment: It seems it does not work because in my real case, the data continent, country and city is called from `computed: {...}`. Seems it's the problem. Seems to have to update  data on `computed: {...}`. But it seems that it can not be done

Comment: Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46213029/how-can-i-reset-dropdown-data-if-modal-closed-on-vue-component. I explain my real case with more detail

Answer (score 2):

I thought I needed to reload, but I was able to move everything inside the mounted hook to an init method.  The mounted hook calls the init method, and if you need the parent to reload everything it can use a ref to call this.$refs.componentName.init();.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest one

For your data in object use your key as **JSON.stringify(data)**

```
  <component :key="JSON.stringify(data)" :data="data" />
```

just update your state

```
$vm.data={
name:'balaji'
}
```

it automaticly update your component

Answer (score 0):

On vuejs3 :

```
<template>
  <render-component :key="count" />
  <span @click="renderComponent">Click to reload render-component</span>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'
export default {
   setup() {
    const count = ref(0)

    const renderComponent = () => {
     count.value++
    }
    return {
     count,
     renderComponent
    }
   }
}
</script>
```

[see gist](https://gist.github.com/jiyuuki/37788d0d3d7434fab4910e165bcaf0f3)

Answer (score -7):

I also face the same issue. I used `location.reload()` for reloading the component.
This may be not the right way to solve this problem. But this solved my problem.