# Attach component to multiple keys

Tags: vue.js, repaint

I have a component that has two attributes that need it to be repainted/rebuild, as the component is not reactive (it is a wrapped jQuery component).

```
<component :template="template" :submit="submit" :data="data"></component>
```

As I found out the `:key` is the right thing to use ([How can I reload a vue component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46211297/how-can-i-reload-a-vue-component), https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/).

But since I have two properties to watch I don't know how to do that.

Two keys result in the error `duplicate attribute: :key`

```
<component :key="data" :key="selected_form" :template="template" :submit="submit" :data="data"></component>
```

And putting them in an array results in the warning `Avoid using non-primitive value as key, use string/number value instead.`

```
<component :key="[data, selected_form]" :template="template" :submit="submit" :data="data"></component>
```

What is the correct/best way of repainting a component if either of the models changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a method that returns some string based on `data` and `selected_form` ..

```
<component :key="getKey(data, selected_form)" :template="template" :submit="submit" :data="data"></component>
```

And in your methods ..

```
methods: {
  getKey(data, selected_form) {
    // return some string based on data and selected_form
  }
}
```

Comment: That works but I can't imagine that this is the elegant solution.

Comment: @white_gecko Granted but I couldn't think of another way.

Comment: Since there is no other answer, this might be the best for the moment. I've also implemented it and it works. But I'm still watching out for better replies ;-)

Answer (score 2):

A simplified version of Husam Ibrahim's answer:

```
<component :key="[data, selected_form].toString()" />
```

any change to `data` or `selected_form` will cause component to refresh

Answer (score 1):

For two keys we can use:

```
<component :key="data && selected_form"></component>
```